# (api) resource group route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When grouping routes through resources as such:

```
Route::resource('books/{book}/catalog', 'CatalogController', ['names' => [
    'index' => 'catalog.index',
    'store' => 'catalog.store',
    'update' => 'catalog.update',
    'destroy' => 'catalog.destroy',
], 'except' => ['create', 'edit', 'show']]);
```

The route:list command outputs:

```
DELETE    | api/v1/books/{book}/catalog/{catalog}
PUT|PATCH | api/v1/books/{book}/catalog/{catalog}
```

However I was hoping for:

```
DELETE    | api/v1/books/{book}/catalog
PUT|PATCH | api/v1/books/{book}/catalog
```

Any suggestions how I can get the results when grouping, without the extra {catalog} parameter in the DELETE and PUT|PATCH routes?

Comment: One option is with Route::prefix and build every route as you expect.

Comment: This is a good point, it groups everything together while still maintaining the option of specifying, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not just using the apiResource method?
It makes it all so much tidier.

```
Route::apiResource('catalog', 'CatalogController');
```

Comment: I do use apiResource whenever I can, however in this case the result is the same. So I am starting to think this isn't posibble without writing the routes as such:
`Route::get('books/{book}/catalog', 'CatalogController@index');`

Comment: So when you reference 'books/{book}/catalog' on an index method what is the wildcard? Are there certain catalogs related to certain books?

Comment: The relation is that, when used, the book/{id} is stored in the user's catalog. Not sure what you mean with wildcard, that's the param in the brackets?

Comment: The output you are getting is completely right. You are essentially telling it to do exactly what you don't want it to do. You are saying give my routes the prefix books/{book}/catalog, you are passing your parameter in your resource name. which I have honestly never seen before.So then when you hit the routes that accept params it's creating the route exactly how it thinks it should be.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that there is a one-to-one relationship between books and catalogs, and that is why you don't need the catalog parameter to determine which catalog to delete/update.

If this is the case, what you're looking for is singular resource routing. Laravel does not provide this by default.

I have created a package that adds this functionality to Laravel: [shiftonelabs/laravel-singular-resource-routes](https://github.com/shiftonelabs/laravel-singular-resource-routes).

One change you would need to make, however, is to change your `index` route to the `show` route. Singular resources are by definition singular, so there isn't a group of resources to `index`, there is only one resource to `show`.

After installing the package, you would update your route to include the `'singular' => true` option (and change your `index` route):

```
Route::resource('books/{book}/catalog', 'CatalogController', [
    'names' => [
        'show' => 'catalog.show',
        'store' => 'catalog.store',
        'update' => 'catalog.update',
        'destroy' => 'catalog.destroy',
    ],
    'except' => ['create', 'edit'],
    'singular' => true,
]);
```